# ¿Cómo puedo dar permisos a mi aplicación Access 2003 para poder trabajar con ella?

Tags: ms-access

Se han cambiado los permisos para mi aplicación Access 2003, y no puedo trabajar con ella:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando intento restablecer permisos, me encuentro con un montón de cosas deshabilitadas:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Cómo se puede hacer para volver a abrirla sin problemas? Gracias